# Get Parent Value Using Nodes() and Value()

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

I have an XML document snippet that matches this XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="QuestionType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="questionId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    <xs:element name="questionDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    <xs:element name="questionHeader" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="questionLabel" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="version" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    <xs:element name="SubQuestion" type="QuestionType"
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This recursively defines a `<Question>` elements that can have an infite number of `<SubQuestion>` elements, both of the type `QuestionType`.

Using SQL, **I'd like to query the document once to get a single result set with all of the questions and sub-questions**. I have two independent queries at the moment to achieve this (*please note that I'm using `NVarChar(1000)` for testing purposes only - they will be more appropriately sized in production, and that `@X` is an XML variable that matches the schema above*):

```
SELECT -- Top-level questions...
  C.value('questionId[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Id,
  NULL ParentId,
  C.value('questionDescription[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Description,
  NULLIF(C.value('questionHeader[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'), '') Header,
  NULLIF(C.value('questionLabel[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'), '') Label,
  C.value('version[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Version
FROM @X.nodes('//Question') X(C);

SELECT -- Sub-questions...
  C.value('questionId[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Id,
  C.query('..').value('(Question/questionId)[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') ParentId,
  C.value('questionDescription[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Description,
  NULLIF(C.value('questionHeader[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'), '') Header,
  NULLIF(C.value('questionLabel[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'), '') Label,
  C.value('version[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Version
FROM @X.nodes('//SubQuestion') X(C);
```

I'd expect this could be solved using a recursive CTE, but I'm having trouble putting one together.

Comment: Sidebar: If your document is going to be very large, XQuery is very slow you might be better off using OpenXml

Comment: @kd7: Right, thanks for pointing that out. I am aware of how painfully slow XQuery can be, but with my documents it should suffice.

Comment: @Yuck: I have two questions: 1) would it be possible for you to post at least an XML snippet (or sample) and not only the XSD? 2) are you looking for an SQL query or would also an XQuery query suit you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have tagged this question with sql-server-2008 and that IMHO SQL Server 2008 has support for XQuery I would like to suggest a different "angle": use an XPath expression to select the nodes you are interested in.

```
.//*[local-name(.) = 'Question' or local-name(.) = 'SubQuestion']
```

Please note that I am using the XPath function local-name() in case your real XML data has namespace declarations.

I have created a sample XML file to test the expression above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Questions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns="http://www.acme.com" xsi:schemaLocation="sample.xsd">
    <Question>
        <questionId>1</questionId>
        <questionDescription>Question 1</questionDescription>
        <version>1</version>
        <SubQuestion>
            <questionId>1.1</questionId>
            <questionDescription>Question 1.1</questionDescription>
            <version>1</version>
            <SubQuestion>
                <questionId>1.1.1</questionId>
                <questionDescription>Question 1.1.1</questionDescription>
                <version>1</version>
                <SubQuestion>
                    <questionId>1.1.1.1</questionId>
                    <questionDescription>Question 1.1.1.1</questionDescription>
                    <version>1</version>
                </SubQuestion>
                <SubQuestion>
                    <questionId>1.1.1.2</questionId>
                    <questionDescription>Question 1.1.1.2</questionDescription>
                    <version>1</version>
                </SubQuestion>
            </SubQuestion>
            <SubQuestion>
                <questionId>1.2</questionId>
                <questionDescription>Question 1.2</questionDescription>
            </SubQuestion>
        </SubQuestion>
    </Question>
    <Question>
        <questionId>2</questionId>
        <questionDescription>Question 2</questionDescription>
        <version>1</version>
    </Question>
    <Question>
        <questionId>3</questionId>
        <questionDescription>Question 3</questionDescription>
        <version>1</version>
        <SubQuestion>
            <questionId>3.1</questionId>
            <questionDescription>Question 3.1</questionDescription>
            <version>1</version>
        </SubQuestion>
    </Question>
</Questions>
```

Evaluating this XQuery query against that sample

```
declare namespace acme = "http://www.acme.com";
<AllQuestions>
 {
   for $question in .//*[local-name(.) = 'Question' or local-name(.) = 'SubQuestion']
   return
        <Question>
            <questionId>{ data($question/acme:questionId) }</questionId>
            <questionDescription>{ data($question/acme:questionDescription) }</questionDescription>
        </Question>
 }
</AllQuestions>
```

will result in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AllQuestions>
   <Question>
      <questionId>1</questionId>
      <questionDescription>Question 1</questionDescription>
   </Question>
   <Question>
      <questionId>1.1</questionId>
      <questionDescription>Question 1.1</questionDescription>
   </Question>
   <Question>
      <questionId>1.1.1</questionId>
      <questionDescription>Question 1.1.1</questionDescription>
   </Question>
   <Question>
      <questionId>1.1.1.1</questionId>
      <questionDescription>Question 1.1.1.1</questionDescription>
   </Question>
   <Question>
      <questionId>1.1.1.2</questionId>
      <questionDescription>Question 1.1.1.2</questionDescription>
   </Question>
   <Question>
      <questionId>1.2</questionId>
      <questionDescription>Question 1.2</questionDescription>
   </Question>
   <Question>
      <questionId>2</questionId>
      <questionDescription>Question 2</questionDescription>
   </Question>
   <Question>
      <questionId>3</questionId>
      <questionDescription>Question 3</questionDescription>
   </Question>
   <Question>
      <questionId>3.1</questionId>
      <questionDescription>Question 3.1</questionDescription>
   </Question>
</AllQuestions>
```

**EDIT - Final Query**

```
SELECT
    C.value('questionId[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Id,
    COALESCE(
      C.query('..').value('(Question/questionId)[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'),
      C.query('..').value('(SubQuestion/questionId)[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)')
    ) ParentId,
    C.value('questionDescription[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Description,
    NULLIF(C.value('questionHeader[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'), '') Header,
    NULLIF(C.value('questionLabel[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'), '') Label,
    C.value('version[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Version
FROM
  @X.nodes('.//*[local-name(.)="Question" or local-name(.)="SubQuestion"]') X(C);
```

Comment: +1 The key to a solution that uses a single query is your XQuery selector at the start of your answer. I'm editing in my final query for the purpose of having it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this so far, although I'm still hoping to compact the query a bit:

```
WITH Q AS (
  SELECT
    C.value('questionId[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Id,
    NULL ParentId,
    C.value('questionDescription[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Description,
    NULLIF(C.value('questionHeader[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'), '') Header,
    NULLIF(C.value('questionLabel[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'), '') Label,
    C.value('version[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Version
  FROM @X.nodes('//Question') X(C)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    C.value('questionId[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Id,
    COALESCE(
      C.query('..').value('(Question/questionId)[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'),
      C.query('..').value('(SubQuestion/questionId)[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)')
    ) ParentId,
    C.value('questionDescription[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Description,
    NULLIF(C.value('questionHeader[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'), '') Header,
    NULLIF(C.value('questionLabel[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'), '') Label,
    C.value('version[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Version
  FROM @X.nodes('//SubQuestion') X(C)
)
SELECT Q.Id, Q.ParentId, Q.Description, Q.Header, Q.Label, Q.Version
FROM Q;
```

This is the important bit, as it will get whichever is the first non-null `ParentId` value:

```
COALESCE(
  C.query('..').value('(Question/questionId)[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'),
  C.query('..').value('(SubQuestion/questionId)[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)')
) ParentId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE:

```
WITH TopLevel (ID, ParentID, Description, Header, Label,Level)
AS
(
SELECT -- Top-level questions...
  C.value('questionId[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Id,
  NULL ParentId,
  C.value('questionDescription[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Description,
  NULLIF(C.value('questionHeader[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'), '') Header,
  NULLIF(C.value('questionLabel[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'), '') Label,
  C.value('version[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Version,
  0 AS Level
FROM @X.nodes('//Question') X(C)
UNION ALL
SELECT -- Sub-questions...
  C.value('questionId[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Id,
  C.query('..').value('(Question/questionId)[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') ParentId,
  C.value('questionDescription[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Description,
  NULLIF(C.value('questionHeader[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'), '') Header,
  NULLIF(C.value('questionLabel[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)'), '') Label,
  C.value('version[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') Version
  ,Level + 1 AS Level
FROM @X.nodes('//SubQuestion') X(C)
JOIN TopLevel AS t ON C.query('..').value('(Question/questionId)[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)') = t.id )

SELECT * FROM TopLevel
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Comment: The trouble with the document structure is that a `<SubQuestion>` may have either a `<Question>` **or** a `<SubQuestion>` for a parent. This CTE only takes into account the former. And I get the error `Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "ParentID" of recursive query "TopLevel".`

Comment: Check the answer, I just added a Level field to it to show how deep the questions/subquestions go. You can always join TopLevel back to itself in the SELECT after the CTE to get the additional subquestion relationships.